# Clicked image is zooming instead of displaying overlay image

Tags: html, css, image

When we click on image, i am adding background color `red` for that image as below in [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/wall1.html):

```
.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:hover, .product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:focus, .product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:active {
        background: red !important;

    }
```

[image]

now instead of background-color , i need to display small `image` [**selected checkbox** ] on clicked image.

[image]

code for 1st image [Triangle] :

**script**

```
for (i=0;i<inner.length;i++){ 
var classN = inner[i].innerText;  
if (classN=="Ared" ||classN=="Agreen" ||classN=="Ayellow" )
inner.eq(i).addClass("colors"); 
classN = classN.toLowerCase(); 
var urlB = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/"+classN+".png"; 
inner.eq(i).css('background-image', 'url(' + urlB + ')'); 
} 
} 
});
```

**css**

```
.colors
{
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

code for 2nd image : [checkbox]

**css**

```
.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:hover, .product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:focus, .product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:active {
    background: none !important;
    background-image: url('http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/image1.PNG');
     z-index: 2; 

}
```

when i add this below css, 1st image displayed in zoom :

```
position: absolute;
     top: 30px;
     left: 70px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these `css` classes as i tested and works fine:

```
.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    background: none !important;
}

.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after {
    /* background: blue; */
    content: url(http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/image1.PNG);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 1; /* updated! */
}


.product-options .input-box ul.options-list .label>label.colors {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

---

**Updated:**

to preload that checkmark back-ground image, such that it not downloaded late only after user select one option, we could change it as following:

```
.product-options input[type="radio"] + span:after {
    content: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/image1.PNG");
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after {
    display: block;
}
```

of course with those prev styles

```
.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    background: none !important;
}

.product-options .input-box ul.options-list .label>label.colors {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```